# How can I use the querystring lib in node to append additional querystrings

Tags: node.js, angular, query-string

I have a url which looks like this:

http://example.com?parm1=foo

I want to use the node querystring [lib](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) to append additional params such as like this:

http://www.example.com?parm1=foo&parm2=bar&parm3=test

I saw that I can define my params like this:

```
querystring.stringify({ parm2: 'bar', param3: 'test' });
```

I'm just not sure how to append this to my current url though

Comment: I've also looked into using nodes url module: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html. But that doesn't seem to be supported in some versions of IE and Edge when appending new querystrings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able to solve it using this lib instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/append-query

Here is an example:

```
const appendQuery = require('append-query');
var newUrl = appendQuery(originalUrl, {width: '40', height: '40'});
```